# getting unusual line chart on weekly time series data in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have weekly car sales data and I made line charts by different car producers. However, I got little unusual line charts because the days one margin like `12-31-xxxx` and `01-01-xxxx` still stays in the same weeks, which gave me quite an unexpected plot. How should I make line charts if week numbers sit on the margins? Is there any better ideas to make this right? Can anyone point me out how to correct this? Thanks

**reproducible data & my attempt**

here is [reproducible data on this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/8a6378ff7c77b1af76d1cb33a018b329/raw/3b38168bd528ef9e7e2bfa1246b91bba1c1dc287/car_sales.csv) that I used for making line chart

**my attempt**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/8a6378ff7c77b1af76d1cb33a018b329/raw/3b38168bd528ef9e7e2bfa1246b91bba1c1dc287/car_sales.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['date'])
# df = df.rename({'Unnamed: 0' : 'date'}, axis=1)
df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

dfww = df.groupby(['company', 'week'])['product_sales_cnt'].agg(['max', 'min', 'mean']).stack().reset_index(level=[2]).rename(columns={'level_2': 'mm', 0: 'vals'}).reset_index()

for g, d in dfww.groupby('company'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4), dpi=144)
    for year in df['year'].unique():
        data = df[(df.date.dt.year == year) & (df.company == g)]
        sns.lineplot(x='week', y='product_sales_cnt', ci=None, data=data, label=year)
plt.ylabel('product_sales_cnt')
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

**current output**

here is the one of the current output that I got from the above code snippet:

[image]

since the data I used, it is going to be updated weekly base, so the plot also going to be consistent with the data. But now, because of the wrong week's number, resulted in a line chart goes wrong. I think because `12-31` and `01-01` shares the same week number, that causes the problem. How should I fix this up? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['week'] = np.select([(df['week'] == 53) & (df['date'].dt.month == 1),
                        (df['week'] == 53) & (df['date'].dt.month == 12)],
                        [1, 52], df['week'])
```

This will ensure that week is either 1 or 52. As shown in the image, 2016 no longer has it's own "Week 53". Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/8a6378ff7c77b1af76d1cb33a018b329/raw/3b38168bd528ef9e7e2bfa1246b91bba1c1dc287/car_sales.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['date'])
# df = df.rename({'Unnamed: 0' : 'date'}, axis=1)
df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['week'] = np.select([(df['week'] == 53) & (df['date'].dt.month == 1),
                        (df['week'] == 53) & (df['date'].dt.month == 12)],
                        [1, 52], df['week'])
df
dfww = df.groupby(['company', 'week'])['product_sales_cnt'].agg(['max', 'min', 'mean']).stack().reset_index(level=[2]).rename(columns={'level_2': 'mm', 0: 'vals'}).reset_index()
for g, d in dfww.groupby('company'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4), dpi=144)
    for year in df['year'].unique():
        data = df[(df.date.dt.year == year) & (df.company == g)]
        sns.lineplot(x='week', y='product_sales_cnt', ci=None, data=data, label=year)
plt.ylabel('product_sales_cnt')
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Per Comments:

[image]

Comment: thank you, this is charm solution! big plus ++ :)

Comment: it is a little odd. why 2021 is not plotted or am I missing something? let's say, I am gonna keep line charts of 2018~2021, the line for `2021` is gone. Why?

Comment: @Adam there is only one data point for 2021. You will need two data points I.E. there is only "Week 1" in the data.

Comment: You previously had a line in there, becuase it was incorrectly 52, so you had a line from week 1 to week 53. NOW, it is just going to week 1. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the perfect solution, but you can convert week number so the first part of the week that continues into new year is `0` by doing this: `df['week']=df['date'].dt.strftime('%W').astype('uint8')` or `'%U'` for week start as Sunday

Comment: thanks for heads up. let's see what else can be done about it.